# Is there a chance that a CentOS machine does not have RPM?

Tags: centos, rpm

I am going to work on a remotely located CentOS machine without internet. I do not know its situation and it is very hard for me to move things between. In other words I have only one-shot for setting it up, so I want to be well-prepared for every possible state of the machine.

I will need some programs, so I downloaded .rpm packages in my Windows machine. I am planning to transfer them to the CentOS machine and install with RPM. The question is whether there is a chance that the machine does not have RPM? And if yes, what should I do to get RPM and install the .rpm packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS is rpm-based; that means that everything on that server is installed with rpms. Theoretically, it is possible that someone removed the `rpm` package, but then you're in big trouble. If it is just any normal CentOS machine, then `rpm` is surely present.

Answer (score 3):

No; if someone removed yum/rpm it's no longer CentOS. You could bring live ISOs of CentOS/Ubuntu/Manjaro in case you need any base system components.  Generally bringing individual rpm files can be a problem because you may be missing the correct version of dependencies, so it's best to bring a copy of a rpm repositories (the base one is included on live ISOs), if you have a fast connection and plenty of free space you can look up how to make a full offline clone of a distributions repositories.

```
yum install -y createrepo yum-utils
reposync -p /var/www/html/repo -r <REPOID> -l
createrepo /var/www/html/repo
```

Comment: Can I make the offline clone on my Windows Pc?

Comment: @trxrg yes, but you may want to install CentOS in virtualbox on Windows to make it easy on yourself https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9892